# Why does Wine give me error when I want to run psiphon

Tags: windows, wine

When I run the following command:

```
wine '/var/www/psiphon.exe'
```

I get the below error:

```
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x4c6ea0 1 4a0000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x68f5b6a0 1 68f40000: stub
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0xece278, overlapped 0xece240): stub
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -210, std (d/m/y): 22/09/2014, dlt (d/m/y): 22/03/2014
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x11de8ac, overlapped 0x11de890): stub
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wine: configuration in '/root/.wine' has been updated.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:ras:RasEnumEntriesW ((nil),(null),0x143180,0x33fa14,0x33fa1c),stub!
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**The program gets started, but does not open filtered sites.**

In firefox I've set: `Use system proxy settings`. Psiphon gives error 404 bad request when psiphon gets connected.